# 401-Unauthorized on importing dataset from kaggle

Tags: dataset, kaggle

I want to download a dataset from kaggle. I followed the steps from this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DofKEdQYaXmDWBzuResXWWvxhLgDeVyl#scrollTo=KixiXyagGy7Y). But I get this error. How do I get authorized or resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and followed these steps:

1. Confirm that your kaggle google account & colab google account is the same
2. Expire all active tokens in your kaggle account
3. Delete any kaggle.json file you have in your pc
4. Generate a new token

Voilà, hope it helps